# SMLoginItemSetEnabled(...) GET counterpart

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For Sandboxed apps, to create a launch item, Apple suggest you use `LSRegisterURL(..)` and `SMLoginItemSetEnabled(..)` along with a helper tool. I've set up everything how I want it but I would like a way (not storing a preference value) to get the status of "if it is registered". Basically a way to perform the same action as `SMLoginItemGetEnabled(...)` would.

EDIT: Here is my final code thanks to Rob Keniger's answer:

```
- (BOOL)startAtLogin {
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary*)SMJobCopyDictionary(kSMDomainUserLaunchd, 
                                                            CFSTR("com.yourcompany.app"));
    BOOL contains = (dict!=NULL);
    [dict release];
    return contains;
}
```

Comment: great question.  I looked through the header files and  symbols exported by the System Management framework and don't see anything super obvious available there (maybe `___launchdJobIsEnabled`?).  You should file an official bug / feature request at bugreporter.apple.com.  And you'll probably have to write a preference, anyways.

Comment: Should "com.yourcompany.app" be your real app's bundle ID or your helper launch-at-login app's bundle ID?

Comment: Either way, not having any luck with your final code here. Returns NO directly after the app is opened at login.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you could use `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries(kSMDomainUserLaunchd)` to get an array containing dictionaries for all the currently active `launchd` jobs.

According to the docs, calling `SMLoginItemSetEnabled()` immediately starts the job in question, so if your login task is not in the list returned by `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries()` then you can probably assume it's not set to run at login.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll have to test it later.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my original post containing my implementation.

Comment: Yours is an even better solution as you're only pulling the one entry from the job list. Great!

Comment: I created some open source code that simplifies the process of using ServiceManagement to add login items: https://github.com/alexzielenski/StartAtLoginController

Comment: `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries` has been deprecated now.

Comment: On `SMCopyAllJobDictionaries` inside `<ServiceManagement/ServiceManagement.h>`




`For the specific use of testing the state of a login item that may have been
  enabled with SMLoginItemSetEnabled() in order to show that state to the
  user, this function remains the recommended API. A replacement API for this
  specific use will be provided before this function is removed.`

We can safely use the method until further notice. Just be sure to check the new SDK releases/updates for the new API and this method's obsolescence.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer was not working for me. This blog says "`// Note: Sandbox issue when using SMJobCopyDictionary()`" which must be the problem. So if you're having trouble using the accepted answer here in the sandbox, give this method a try. Working for me.

All credit to Mike Cohen for this. See his blog post for more:

http://blog.mcohen.me/2012/01/12/login-items-in-the-sandbox/

```
-(BOOL)appIsPresentInLoginItems
{
    NSString *bundleID = @"com.madebynotion.myLoginHelper";
    NSArray * jobDicts = nil;
    jobDicts = (NSArray *)SMCopyAllJobDictionaries( kSMDomainUserLaunchd );
    // Note: Sandbox issue when using SMJobCopyDictionary()

    if ( (jobDicts != nil) && [jobDicts count] > 0 ) {

        BOOL bOnDemand = NO;

        for ( NSDictionary * job in jobDicts ) {

            if ( [bundleID isEqualToString:[job objectForKey:@"Label"]] ) {
                bOnDemand = [[job objectForKey:@"OnDemand"] boolValue];
                break;
            } 
        }

        CFRelease((CFDictionaryRef)jobDicts); jobDicts = nil;
        return bOnDemand;

    } 
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately SMCopyAllJobDictionaries deprecated.